# Deploying Angular-Fullstack (MEAN) on Google App Engine

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, mean-stack, angular-fullstack

I've generated a project with Yeoman Angular-Fullstack generator (https://github.com/angular-fullstack/generator-angular-fullstack).

I created an app.yaml and tried to deploy the project on GAE with command:

```
gcloud app deploy
```

But I'm getting an error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [13] Timed out when starting VMs.  It's possible that the application code is unhealthy.  (0/2 ready, 2 still deploying).
```

Any tips on how to debug the gcloud deploy? I'm running the latest gcloud SDK.

--

Here's a longer debug trace:

```
Updating service [default]...-DEBUG: Operation [apps/<MY-PROJECT>/operations/63e50c89-da5f-4697-aeea-447865a82cc4] not complete. Waiting 5s.
Updating service [default]...|DEBUG: Operation [apps/<MY-PROJECT>/operations/63e50c89-da5f-4697-aeea-447865a82cc4] complete. Result: {
    "metadata": {
        "target": "apps/<MY-PROJECT>/services/default/versions/20160804t151734", 
        "method": "google.appengine.v1beta5.Versions.CreateVersion", 
        "user": "<MY-EMAIL>@gmail.com", 
        "insertTime": "2016-08-04T12:16:31.905Z", 
        "endTime": "2016-08-04T12:24:03.526Z", 
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.appengine.v1beta5.OperationMetadataV1Beta5"
    }, 
    "done": true, 
    "name": "apps/<MY-PROJECT>/operations/63e50c89-da5f-4697-aeea-447865a82cc4", 
    "error": {
        "message": "Timed out when starting VMs.  It's possible that the application code is unhealthy.  (0/2 ready, 2 still deploying).", 
        "code": 13
    }
}
Updating service [default]...failed.
DEBUG: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [13] Timed out when starting VMs.  It's possible that the application code is unhealthy.  (0/2 ready, 2 still deploying).
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jp/softaa/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/cli.py", line 719, in Execute
    result = args.calliope_command.Run(cli=self, args=args)
  File "/Users/jp/softaa/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/backend.py", line 1404, in Run
    resources = command_instance.Run(args)
  File "/Users/jp/softaa/google-cloud-sdk/lib/surface/app/deploy.py", line 57, in Run
    return deploy_util.RunDeploy(self, args)
  File "/Users/jp/softaa/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/command_lib/app/deploy_util.py", line 215, in RunDeploy
    api_client.DeployService(name, version, service, manifest, image)
  File "/Users/jp/softaa/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/app/appengine_api_client.py", line 89, in DeployService
    return operations.WaitForOperation(self.client.apps_operations, operation)
  File "/Users/jp/softaa/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/app/api/operations.py", line 70, in WaitForOperation
    encoding.MessageToPyValue(completed_operation.error)))
OperationError: Error Response: [13] Timed out when starting VMs.  It's possible that the application code is unhealthy.  (0/2 ready, 2 still deploying).
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [13] Timed out when starting VMs.  It's possible that the application code is unhealthy.  (0/2 ready, 2 still deploying).
```

Comment: All it says is your code is unhealthy we cannot do anything about that. I ran a search for the search term and mostly that was the response from people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GAE does not come with Mongo. You have two options

1. Use GAE flex and build your own mongo container and use it
2. Use a Mongo cloud provider like https://mlab.com and they even have a free version to test.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is just about finding the cause of this error, I would recommend using the Development Server on your localhost to find the error.
Without taking a deeper look, I guess the Node part does not fulfil the requirements for GAE or you are trying to deploy to a region where Node Applications are not supported.

Comment: The app runs ok on localhost ("npm start"). I think it's failing because there's no Mongo instance available in gcloud. I'm just struggling to find a proper error message as I'm not very familiar with this PaaS.